# как проверить строку на наличие букв в верхнем и нижнем регистре

Tags: javascript

надо сделать так чтоб при вводе слова функция проверяла что слово имеет буквы верхнего и нижнего регистра и тогда выводила true

Answer (score 2):

```js
function mixedCase(str) {
  str = "" + str;
  return str != str.toLowerCase() && str != str.toUpperCase();
}

console.log(mixedCase("Ivanko"));
console.log(mixedCase("ivanko"));
console.log(mixedCase("IVANKO"));

console.log(mixedCase(123));
console.log(mixedCase(null));
console.log(mixedCase());
console.log(mixedCase({}));
```

Comment: а как приводить код так, что бы его можно было здесь запускать?

Comment: @helldrg В тулбаре редактора ответа (и вопроса) есть кнопка "Фрагмент кода".

Comment: спасибо большое!